# Routing in static html landing page

Tags: html, .htaccess, routes, static-pages

I have a small portfolio landing page based on js/css/html. No frameworks/CMS, just pure static html. Entry point is `index.html` file with content on English language.

I want to use translations on my site: `index.ru.html`, `index.ua.html`, but I don't want to see any `*.html` or `index.ua` in the address bar. User can change a language by buttons on top of my page.

How can I route:

1. `http://mysite/en` to display `index.html` - first enter to site
2. `http://mysite/ru` to display `index.ru.html`
3. `http://mysite/ua` to display `index.ua.html`

?

Also can I route to specific div/section html tag: user enter `http://mysite/ru/contacts` to display contacts section in `index.ru.html`? Scrolling page also must change url... is it real or not?

Maybe I need to use micro-framework for my small needs?

**EDIT:**

Found good example on this site - http://www.even.lv/

Comment: Have you tried making each a separate subdomain? That seems to be what a lot of websites use.

Comment: @RobertRose, You mean `en.mysite.com` etc? I don't think it's good for SEO and domain name becomes ugly. Even Microsoft with their [locale list](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/locale.aspx) doesn't do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding this to your Root/.htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^en/?$ index.html [NC,L] 
RewriteRule ^(ru|ua)$ index.$1.html [NC,L]
```

This will redirect "/en" to "/index.html" and "/ru" to "index.ru.html".

Comment: It works with ru/ua correctly, but not redirect from `mysite.com` to `mysite.com/en`

Answer (score 0):

Might be using bootstrap scroll spy you can take user to sepecific section. if you don't want url to be change in that case ajax will help you. with use of  jQuery you can trigger select change function jQuery("#language-select").change(function(){ // your logic try ajax here to change portion on page.  })

Answer (score 0):

Make directories for each language and put the relevant pages inside.

The only mechanism you have that allows you to omit a full url is the ability of the web server to serve a "default" page, which in your case is an index.html

By the same token to support mysite/ru/contacts you would need a directory structure of:

```
mysite/
      ru/
        contacts/
             index.html
```

In other words, with pure html pages and without using rewrites, you can accomplish your structure with directories off the webroot and creating many individual index.html pages.

The other option is to use rewrite rules like those available using mod_rewrite and the apache web server.

Those rules require a good working understanding of regular expressions.

Comment: This idea came to my head when I'm asked this question =) But what about entry point? I need redirect or something from root to `/en` catalogue with `index.html` on English.

Comment: Your root index.html can be assumed to be English.  You still need an /en directory tree for all the other pages, but not for the default/home page.

Answer (score 0):

we can use onclick event listener on that list items where we want to use route.
for example -

```
const page1 = document.querySelector("#page1"); // selecting list item from nav bar with it's id

const page2 = document.querySelector("#page2"); // selecting list item from nav bar with it's id

page1.addEventListener("click", function () {
  window.location.href = "./page1.html";
});

page2.addEventListener("click", function () {
  window.location.href = "./page2.html";
}); 

and same goes for home page - 
const home = document.querySelector("#home")
home.addEventListener("click", function () {
  window.location.href = "./index.html";
});
```